# I'm getting this error on android studio when trying to generate a signed apk file. How can i fix this

Tags: android, webview

> Task :app:processDebugResources
> AAPT2 aapt2-7.3.1-8691043-windows Daemon #0 Failed to shutdown within timeout
> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: AAPT2 aapt2-7.3.1-8691043-windows Daemon #0: Failed to shut down within 30 seconds. Forcing shutdown
> at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.stopProcess(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:253)
> at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.shutDown(Aapt2Daemon.kt:171)
> at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.handleError(Aapt2Daemon.kt:206)
> at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.handleError$default(Aapt2Daemon.kt:190)
> at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.link(Aapt2Daemon.kt:131)
> at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.link(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:176)
> at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$leasingAapt2Daemon$1.link(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:199)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.services.PartialInProcessResourceProcessor.link(PartialInProcessResourceProcessor.kt:51)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ProcessResourcesRunnableKt.processResources(Aapt2ProcessResourcesRunnable.kt:74)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$Companion.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.kt:907)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$Companion.access$invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.kt:754)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction.run(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.kt:383)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfileAwareWorkAction.execute(ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt:74)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
> at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:205)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
> at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:270)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:119)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:124)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
> Suppressed: java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed
> at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:354)
> at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
> at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
> at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:318)
> at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:153)
> at java.base/java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:251)
> at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:257)
> at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.stopProcess(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:243)
> ... 47 more

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> AAPT2 aapt2-7.3.1-8691043-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that something related to Gradle, so did you change your gradle plugin?

please share plugin version from here:

File->Project-Structure->Project

Android Gradle Plugin Version

Possible issue:

1-if you have any change, please revert.

2-check also if you changed java home directory or updated java.

3-if you have any service pack in windows,

4-if you updated any C++ runtime .....